# Transfer data between client and Codebehind using Property of User Control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a user control with a grid on an aspx page. I want the column which is being edited in the grid and perform some logic based on that on server side(.aspx.cs). So, I created a public property and a private field for user control and I want to set this property value on the client side using JavaScript as column editing is a client side event for the grid.

I am not sure on how to set the value of the property on client side(in .aspx) using JS and access its updated value on user controls' codebehind. Can anyone point me out how to do this and get the value of property to my codebehind?

Here is my sample code.

```
private string _assignedToCol;
    public string AssignedColumn
    {
        get
        {
            return this._assignedToCol;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                this._assignedToCol = value;
        }
    }
```

`_assignedToCol` is the member variable of user control and `AssignedColumn` is the associated property for that.

Comment: If you store the value in a HiddenField control on the client-side then you can retrieve it in your code behind.

Comment: Yes. The hidden field is stored in the aspx/ascx view state